# What squad members romance together without Shepard?

Tags: mass-effect-series

I didn't romance any character in the first two games, but romanced Liara in the last part.

Now, I found Garrus and Tali kissing in the main gun calibration room and wondered if there are any other intra-squad member romance scenes? For example, would Garrus be with Liara if I had romanced Tali instead? Would Tali be with Liara if I romanced Garrus as a FemShep?

I'm not interested only in this trio, but curious in general: which teammates romance each other in *Mass Effect*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is one of only two *visible* romances on board, other than your own.  The other is Ken and Gabby, as per @ERazER's comment.  I personally haven't seen that one.  While it may be implied that other relationships may happen, there isn't a scene to walk in on for them.  In any case, they don't involve your squad mates, except Joker and EDI.  Can't see them making out either.

Comment: afaik joker-edi and garrus-tali are the only ones

Comment: @yx.: It's implied Ken and Gabby hook up at one point, I think.

Comment: fair enough, I kind of always assumed they were together

Comment: @yx.: Kasumi says they'd make such a nice couple, if only they realized it.  Considering that she's pretty much the most observant character (not just squad mate) in ME2, it's pretty safe to say they weren't together during ME2.

Comment: You can walk in on Ken and Gabby, in the same place, where Jack resides on the normandy in ME2.

Comment: A note about Ken and Gabby, there's a bug that unfortunately links whether or not you're friends with Ashley to Ken and Gabby's ambient dialogue and resulting romance occurring. [Bioware is aware of it, but says a fix is unlikely to come](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/325/index/10147092/2#10224650). I was very, very sad about this, as while I saved them, I did not have Ashley, so I missed out on it. :(

Comment: @FAE I think that's the reason I missed the scene!

Comment: As of June 26 the bug seems to be fixed in the Extended Cut.

Answer (score 5):

Ashley and James Vega hook up during the Citadel DLC: